# Error - ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `‘ESRI'. while running ogr2ogr command

Tags: gdal, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I have installed gdal

```
$ conda install -c esri gdal
```

And then tried to run the command to merge 2 shapefiles

```
$ ogr2ogr -f ‘ESRI Shapefile’ n4600e00800_30.tif_highlight-1.shp n4600e00900_30.tif_highlight-1.shp
```

but getting error

```
ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `‘ESRI'.
```

Not sure if the driver needs to be installed separately as couldn't find much on this error.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘...’ quotes are the problem. Try double quotes: `-f "ESRI Shapefile"`

I'm not sure this is going to do what you expect. `ogr2ogr` converts between formats, it doesnt merge files. In your case it will results in a shapefile called n4600e00800_30.tif_highlight-1.shp that is identical to n4600e00900_30.tif_highlight-1.shp. Transformations between the same format are generally only useful if you add a filter, are changing coordinate reference system, etc.

What you are probably looking for is `ogrmerge.py` which should be callable from your CLI after installing GDAL. Your command should look like this then:

```
ogrmerge.py -o merged.shp n4600e00800_30.tif_highlight-1.shp n4600e00900_30.tif_highlight-1.shp
```

You can also add `-f "ESRI Shapefile"` to ensure that it writes to the correct format but it'll guess the format from the extension, `.shp` is a pretty safe bet that it'll get it right.